# LUIS cognitive programmatic get all intents

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

LUIS cognitive programmatic get all intents returns the default 100 intents. I want all the intents to be returned. How can we do that?

Comment: Would the [get version intent list API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c0d) give you what you need?

Answer (score 2):

Set the `take` param to 500 to get all items in one time.

> take (optional) integer
>
> The number of entries to return. Maximum page
>   size is 500. **Default is 100.**

So your request will look like the following:

```
https://[location].api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/{appId}/versions/{versionId}/intents?take=500
```

Comment: My question is regarding this api
https://github.com/andreluizsecco/Cognitive-LUIS-Programmatic/wiki/get-started
Get All Intents Async method returns only 100. In the code for GetAllIntentsAsync there is no option to use "take" optional parameter

Comment: If you look at the sources of the project you mention, it is making an underlying call to the official API from LUIS that I am mentioning, https://github.com/andreluizsecco/Cognitive-LUIS-Programmatic/blob/master/Cognitive.LUIS.Programmatic/LuisProgClient.cs#L128

So you can make a pull request on this project to add this feature

Answer (score 0):

It only gives you 100 at a time. Did you use the skip and take querystring params?

Answer (score 0):

Komarl, Check this out 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-boundaries 
I have helped in something.

Comment: The user is asking about the data provided by the API: there can be up to 500 intents as your link details, but here this link may not be relevant